# How to specify more than one IssuerSigningKey in UseJwtBearerAuthentication?

Tags: oauth

I have a REST api using OAuth bearer token authentication. Token is signed by an asymmetric key and REST api validates the token using public key. I got the code work like below. However, there is a case I need to handle when key needs to update. I am thinking to have a secondary public key passed in and let the framework validate token first using primary key and then secondary key. In this way, when I need to update key, I can easily add secondary key, swap and retire. The issue is looking at code below it only takes one signing key. Is there a way to specify multiple?

```
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);

        // codes to get signningKey ignored here

        app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
            new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
            {
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new RsaSecurityKey(signingKey)
                },
            });
    }
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I think I figured it out. There are two ways. One simply straight forward way is to use IssuerSigningKeys property (how could I not discovery it at first place). The code looks like this:

```
        app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
            new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
            {
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    IssuerSigningKeys = new List<RsaSecurityKey>
                    {
                        Utils.GetSigningKey(isPrimary: true),
                        Utils.GetSigningKey(isPrimary: false)
                    },
                },
            });
```

The second approach is to customized IOAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider. The code looks like this: First,

```
        app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
            new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AllowedAudiences = new string[] { "*" },
                IssuerSecurityTokenProviders = new List<IIssuerSecurityTokenProvider>()
                {
                    // Dummy object which won't be used anywhere. It is used to work around parameter validation error about no token provider specified.
                    new SymmetricKeyIssuerSecurityTokenProvider("dummy", "dummy")
                },

                // This is where validation work happens.
                Provider = new BearerAuthenticationProvider(app)
            });
```

Then, the BearerAuthenticationProvider class:

```
/// <summary>
/// Bearer authentication provider.
/// </summary>
public class BearerAuthenticationProvider : IOAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider
{
    /// <summary>
    /// App config.
    /// </summary>
    private readonly IAppBuilder appConfig;

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles applying the authentication challenge to the response message.
    /// </summary>
    public Func<OAuthChallengeContext, Task> OnApplyChallenge { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles processing OAuth bearer token.
    /// </summary>
    public Func<OAuthRequestTokenContext, Task> OnRequestToken { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles validating the identity produced from an OAuth bearer token.
    /// </summary>
    public Func<OAuthValidateIdentityContext, Task> OnValidateIdentity { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="T:Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider" /> class
    /// </summary>
    public BearerAuthenticationProvider(IAppBuilder appConfig)
    {
        this.appConfig = appConfig;
        this.OnRequestToken = (OAuthRequestTokenContext context) =>
        {
            var idContext = new OAuthValidateIdentityContext(context.OwinContext, null, null);

            this.ValidateIdentity(idContext);
            return Task.FromResult<int>(0);
        };
        this.OnValidateIdentity = (OAuthValidateIdentityContext context) => Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        this.OnApplyChallenge = (OAuthChallengeContext context) => Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles applying the authentication challenge to the response message.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public Task ApplyChallenge(OAuthChallengeContext context)
    {
        return this.OnApplyChallenge(context);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles processing OAuth bearer token.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public virtual Task RequestToken(OAuthRequestTokenContext context)
    {
        return this.OnRequestToken(context);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles validating the identity produced from an OAuth bearer token.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public virtual Task ValidateIdentity(OAuthValidateIdentityContext context)
    {
        const string AuthHeaderName = "Authorization";
        if (context.Request.Headers.ContainsKey(AuthHeaderName))
        {
            var jwt = context.Request.Headers[AuthHeaderName].Replace("Bearer ", string.Empty);
            var token = new JwtSecurityToken(jwt);
            var claimIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(token.Claims, "ExternalBearer");

            var param = new TokenValidationParameters()
            {
                ValidateAudience = false,
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                IssuerSigningKeys = new List<RsaSecurityKey>
                {
                    Utils.GetSigningKey(isPrimary: true),
                    Utils.GetSigningKey(isPrimary: false)
                },
            };

            SecurityToken securityToken = null;
            var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var identity = handler.ValidateToken(token.RawData, param, out securityToken);

            var claimPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(claimIdentity);
            context.Response.Context.Authentication.User = claimPrincipal;
            context.Validated(claimIdentity);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Invalid authorization header.");
        }

        return this.OnValidateIdentity(context);
    }
}
```

First approach initializes two signing keys at app startup and only way to make change is when process restarts. the second approach retrieves keys at run time so key rollover doesn't require a service restart.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to have multiple security keys, you can use the benefit of IssuerSigningKeys property, where you can add all the keys you would like to use for authentication.